# State of Health of Lithium Ion Battery

Tags: electricity, batteries

The formula to predict the state of health of a battery is
$$\text{state of health} = \frac{C_i}{C_0}$$
where $C_i$ is its capacity after $i$ cycles and $C_0$ is its initial capacity. My initial capacity should be always greater than the remaining cycles capacity?

Comment: You have *defined* state of health.  It is not a predictive formula unless you know a formula for $C_i$

Comment: Actually, I am having a certain number of discharge cycles. For example, I am having 100 cycles and for each discharge cycle, I am having Capacity . So I am saying Ci as ith cycle capacity value. In that my initial capacity should be always greater than the remaining cycle capacity?